# Typeof Object and its objects

Tags: typescript, formik

I want to generate a type which receives a generic Interface.
This type should return the type of the object or the objects inside the object (if there are).

I made this:

```js
import { FormikValues, FormikTouched, FormikContextType } from 'formik';

type InnerTouched<Obj extends FormikValues> = Obj[keyof Obj] extends FormikValues
  ? FormikTouched<Obj> | InnerTouched<Obj[keyof Obj]>
  : FormikTouched<Obj>;
```

For those who are not familiar with Formik, FormikValues look like that:

```js
export interface FormikValues {
    [field: string]: any;
}
```

Now I try to use that type inside a function:

```js
const setFieldProps = <Fields extends FormikValues>(form: FormikContextType<Fields>) => {
  // ...
    const touched = !!namePathWithoutLast.reduce((acc: InnerTouched<Fields>, current: string) => acc[current], form.touched);
  // ...
};
```

Now I am receiving the following error:
`Argument of type 'FormikTouched<Fields>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InnerTouched<Fields>'` for the form.touched argument.

Type of form.touched is

```js
FormikTouched<Fields>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `InnerTouched` type is redundant because the `FormikTouched` type does this already:

```
export type FormikTouched<Values> = {
  [K in keyof Values]?: Values[K] extends any[]
    ? Values[K][number] extends object
      ? FormikTouched<Values[K][number]>[]
      : boolean
    : Values[K] extends object
    ? FormikTouched<Values[K]>
    : boolean;
};
```

[Source code](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/3a9c707c8eec200d6eae2955536fb987daf38854/packages/formik/src/types.tsx#L26)

---

It looks like you are trying to access a property by going through each element of its path on a nested object, ie o => o.a => o.a.b. This is always tough for Typescript because the type of `acc` changes at each step.

In this particular case, the values at each level of the `form.touched` are one of: a `boolean`, another `FormikTouched` object, an array of `FormikTouched` objects, or `undefined`. It's the `undefined` that gives me an error if I try to write

```
const touched = !!namePathWithoutLast.reduce(
  (acc: FormikTouched<Fields>, current: string) => acc[current], 
  form.touched
);
```

If we say that `acc` can be `undefined` then now `acc[current]` is a problem.

We know that our final value should be a `boolean`, but if we say that `acc` *can* be a `boolean` then accessing the `current` property on `acc` is a problem.  If we say that `acc` *can't* be a `boolean` then returning `acc[current]` is a problem because we know that it might be a `boolean`.

TypeScript expects the value returned from `reduce()` to be assignable to accumulator of the next iteration.  The idea that we only ever hit a `boolean` on the last index is too complex.

At the very best, we would need to describe `acc` as `FormikTouched<FormikValues>` instead of `FormikTouched<Fields>` because the generic changes with every iteration.  It becomes `FormikTouched<Fields[FirstKey]>` and so on.

```
const touched = !!namePathWithoutLast.reduce(
  (acc: FormikTouched<FormikValues>[] | FormikTouched<FormikValues> | undefined | boolean, current: string) => 
    typeof acc === "object" ? acc[current] : false,
  form.touched
);
```

This is damn-near impossible to type correctly.  Everytime I address one issue, another pops up. In this version I've allowed that `acc` might be an `array`, but `acc[current]` is a problem because `current` is a `string` and Typescript won't let you access an `array` property with a `string` (even though at runtime `someArray["5"]` is fine).

So if you don't want to go insane then I think you need to make some sort of type assertion.  I would assert that `acc[current]` is `FormikTouched<FormikValues>`, knowing that at the very last return it's actually `boolean`.

```
const touched = !!namePathWithoutLast.reduce(
  (acc: FormikTouched<FormikValues>, current: string) => acc[current] as FormikTouched<FormikValues>,
  form.touched
);
```

There's a potential for runtime errors if your assertion turns out to be incorrect, but it will resolve your compile-time Typescript issues.

Comment: The idea about having `InnerTouched` is to define `acc` as all the objects options instead of `FormikTouched<FormikValues>`. That's why my `InnerTouched` interface is not really what `FormikTouched` gives. Unfortunately, It isn't solve my issue.